# Shell coding met segmentation fault

Tags: linux, shell, segmentation-fault

I have a piece of shell code ***run.sh*** like below:

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="../../lib"


mp3proc=mp3proc
if [ ! -f "$mp3proc" ]; then
        ln -s mp3decode $mp3proc
fi

inputsonglist="$1"
intputflag="$2

cat $inputsonglist | while read line
do
    echo "$line"
    ./"mp3proc" ${line} $inputflag
done
```

in which, **inputsonglist** is a txt file which stored full path of mp3 files list to be processed like below:

```
/home/user_01/music/wcbz.mp3
/home/user_01/music/wf_hh.mp3
/home/user_01/music/zj_lw.mp3
/home/user_01/music/zj_jjdzf.mp3
/home/user_01/music/zj_jsqsjywwd.mp3
/home/user_01/music/zj_sh.mp3
/home/user_01/music/zj_tbaw.mp3
```

**mp3proc** is my execetuable program which accept two parameters:

1. full mp3 path which locates the mp3 file
2. flag, 0 or 1

However, when I run this shell script like this:

```
./run.sh list.txt 0
```

I met following errors:

```
/home/user_01/music/wcbz.mp3
./run.sh: line 27: 21068 Segmentation fault      ./"mp3proc" ${line} $inputflag
/home/user_01/music/wf_hh.mp3
./run.sh: line 27: 21069 Segmentation fault      ./"mp3proc" ${line} $inputflag
/home/user_01/music/zj_lw.mp3
./run.sh: line 27: 21070 Segmentation fault      ./"mp3proc" ${line} $inputflag
/home/user_01/music/zj_jjdzf.mp3
./run.sh: line 27: 21071 Segmentation fault      ./"mp3proc" ${line} $inputflag
/home/user_01/music/zj_jsqsjywwd.mp3
./run.sh: line 27: 21072 Segmentation fault      ./"mp3proc" ${line} $inputflag
/home/user_01/music/zj_sh.mp3
./run.sh: line 27: 21073 Segmentation fault      ./"mp3proc" ${line} $inputflag
```

I don't know why there are **"Segmentation fault"** happened here ???!!!

Anybody help? Many thanks!

Comment: You have intputflag and inputflag.

Comment: Something wrong with your `mp3proc`, obviously. Have you tried debugging it? We can help if you show its code (then it would be a C or C++ question, please retag accordingly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) try invoking directly `mp3proc`, and see it if segfaults. Then use: `strace -f mp3proc`  and see its output

2) check the LD_IBRARY_PATH: replace with the absolute path, or modify it